Setting today as end date in power bi calendar
Im struggling to setting today as the end date on my calendar in Power Bi. I would like the end date to always open as today, but the user should also have the freedom to change the range if they wish. Is there any way to do this?(https://i.sstatic.net/O93zB9y1.png)
I tried to create measures and new date tables, but nothing seems to work as i expected

Unfortunately, programmatic slicer defaults are still not a feature in Power BI.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Not much to go on... How are you creating your calendar?
You could use DAX to create the calendar using CALENDAR(MINX('FactSales',[SaleDate]),TODAY())

pls see if this works for you as well.
Measure = if(max('Table'[Date])<=today(),1)

and add that measure to the filter visual, select measure is 1. Then the end date will be today automatically.


Hi Ryan, thanks for taking the time to answer my question! With that measure you suggested I can't select other days after todays date, I have data in dates that goes beyond today and should be displayed in the calendar

I thought you want to set today as the end date. If you did that,  then you can't select the date after today.
